# Grid/Datagrid not expanding into space

Tags: wpf, layout, visibility

I have a grid with 4 rows 2 contain datagrids. I want to show/hide one datagrid based on the ShowPackages checkbox. The code all works correctly and is showing/hiding the datagrid. However, the problem is that the other datagrid in the 2nd row isn't expanding into the available space.

I understand this may potentially to be with defining the 4 rows and all these rendering into the space stated. How do I achieve the functionality required?

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Content="Show Completed" IsChecked="{Binding ShowCompletedCommand}" Margin="3"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Show Packages" IsChecked="{Binding ShowPackages}" Margin="3"/>
        </StackPanel>    
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding WorkOrders}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedWorkOrder}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>        
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{Binding ShowPackages, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Packages}" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="3">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" Content="Refresh"/>
                <Button Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" Content="Cancel"/>
            </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second RowDefinition height must be auto:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Edit. This approach should work

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="RowDefinition">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="*"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=PackagesCB, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </RowDefinition.Style>
        </RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox Content="Show Completed" IsChecked="{Binding ShowCompletedCommand}" Margin="3"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="PackagesCB" Content="Show Packages" IsChecked="{Binding ShowPackages}" Margin="3"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding WorkOrders}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedWorkOrder}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Packages}"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" Content="Refresh"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" Content="Cancel"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This will grow with the datagrid's content. I basically wanted each datagrid to be 1* when checked. When set to collapsed the other grid should become 2* and fill the space.

Comment: Works like a dream, I had a work around binding the height to the VM but this is self contained all in the view so a much better option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change to :

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Unfortunately no different.